# format datetime to show timezone offset using jstl

Tags: java, datetime, jstl

I want to show the timezone offset using the jstl.

using the z in the format i m getting GMT or GST but i want to append the datetime with the offset (+0100) or (+0530).

Sample code -

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:formatDate value="${row.time}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"/>
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `'Z'` for that:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${row.time}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"/>
```

please refer to [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)